# Contar xx segundos a partir de cero

Tags: python, time

necesito un ejemplo de cómo contar segundos a partir de 0.
Es decir, tengo una variable Lenght con el tiempo final en segundos, supongo que debo hacer un bucle que empiece de cero y vaya contando segundo a segundo y al llegar al valor Lenght, salga del mismo.
Pueden ayudarme con el código?
Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], la idea de la comunidad es apoyarnos a resolver dudas concretas de programación; me temo que si no muestras que llevas, tu pregunta termine cerrada

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import sleep


Segundos=3
Contador=0
while Contador < Segundos:  
    print(Contador)
    sleep(1)           
    Contador+=1
```

Nose si era esto lo que pedias espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo pero preguntas que no muestran avance o intento alguno no se deben responder

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

def contarHasta (tiempo):
    contador = 1
    while contador <= tiempo:
        print(contador)
        time.sleep(1) #el tiempo que quieres que espere en segundos
        contador += 1

contarHasta(10)
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda